# Usuário deveria acessar uma url que tenha uma query string com o parâmetro "max" e a partir disso, mostrar apenas celulares com preco especifico

Tags: express.js, get, crud, querystring

Preciso filtrar a lista de celulares em função do preço. O usuário deveria acessar uma url que tenha uma query string com o parâmetro "max". A partir desse parâmetro nós temos que devolver a lista de celulares contudo mostrando apenas aqueles cujo preço não supere o do parâmetro "max".

Por exemplo, se o usuário acessar a url /celulares?max=20000 deveríamos listar todos os modelos menos o "Samsung Galaxy A50"

Eu queria entender o que estou fazendo de errado.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const celulares = [
    {
        nome: 'Motorola Moto E6 Plus',
        preco: 14999
    },
    {
        nome: 'Motorola Moto G7',
        preco: 19999
    },
    {
        nome: 'Alcatel 5033A',
        preco: 6999
    },
    {
        nome: 'Samsung Galaxy A50',
        preco: 33499
    }
];


router.get('/celulares', (req, res) => {

    const precoCel = celulares.filter(celular => (celular.preco < 20000));

    res.send(req.query.precoCel)
})
```

Answer (score -3):

De acordo com seu código, cada requisição terá como resposta a queryString `precoCel` (`res.send.(req.query.precoCel`). Então ajustei (abaixo) para retornar a lista de celulares filtrados (ou não, dependendo da queryString).

Também faltou uma pequena validação da queryString, pois ela pode ou não ser informada.

```js
app.get("/celulares", (req, res) => {
  const precoMax = +req.query.max;

  // isNaN verifica se um valor é um número ou não
  const celularesFiltrados = isNaN(precoMax)
    ? celulares
    : celulares.filter((celular) => celular.preco < precoMax);

  res.json(celularesFiltrados);
});
```